# How to solve this type of gradle error in android studio?

Tags: android, gradle

I have tried to solve this problem for 3 months but I always failed to solve it?

```
Error:The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)
<a href="fixGradleVersionInWrapper">Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project</a><br><a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a>
```

Comment: have you tried reimporting the project as stated in the info?

Comment: The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper

Comment: What is your Android Studio version ?. Also what is your `classpath` of root `build.gradle`.?

Comment: how I add the supported version of Gradle?
my android studio version is 3.0.1
please help me to solve this problem.it really made me tired of coding

Comment: this is the classpath of my build.gradle
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1"
    }

Answer (score 0):

change your gradle version to latest in project level build.gradle file.

Answer (score -1):

Open your android studio. Go to Tools -> Android -> Sync project with Gradle File.

Happy Coding...

Answer (score -1):

Just like they said, Open your studio. Go to `file->settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle`.
My friend in [university](https://paperleaf.ca/university-essay/) had the same problem like you. I think that he solved it. I will talk to him and dm you what he said.